# Azure Powershell script to remove/filter line which has extra delimiter from blob

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell

I have a file in blob storage which contains 5 delimiter(columns). Few line contains more than 5 delimiters. I need to remove the lines which contains more than 5 delimiters from the Azure Blob and store into another blob.

Source blob:

```
A;B;C;D;E
A;B;C;D;E
A;B;C;D;E;F
A;B;C;D;E
A;B;C;D;E;F;G
A;B;C;D;E
```

Destination blob should be:

```
A;B;C;D;E
A;B;C;D;E
A;B;C;D;E
A;B;C;D;E
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps? (not really familiar with blobs..)

```
$blob = @"
A;B;C;D;E
A;B;C;D;E
A;B;C;D;E;F
A;B;C;D;E
A;B;C;D;E;F;G
A;B;C;D;E
"@

$blob -split '\r?\n' | ForEach-Object {($_ -split ';')[0..4] -join ';'}
```

---

I may have misread this question (thanks Mathias) and you want to **remove** the lines that have more than 5 items.

```
$blob = @"
A;B;C;D;E
A;B;C;D;E
A;B;C;D;E;F
A;B;C;D;E
A;B;C;D;E;F;G
A;B;C;D;E
"@

$blob -split '\r?\n' | Where-Object { @($_ -split ';').Count -eq 5 }
```

Comment: Sounds more like OP wants to _discard_ the overflowing rows (rather than truncating them)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Ah, yes. I didn't count the lines and thought the OP wanted to remove the extra fields.

Comment: Thanks for your solution to remove line which has extra delimiter. Please suggest how to upload this content as a file in Blob storage

Comment: @AISathish For that, append `| Set-Content -Path 'X:\Folder\TheNewBlob.txt'` to save the result as text file (or whatever you want as extension) and use [Set-AzureStorageBlobContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/set-azurestorageblobcontent?view=azurermps-6.13.0) or the newer [Set-AzStorageBlobContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/set-azstorageblobcontent?view=azps-7.1.0) to upload to an Azure Storage blob.